# EXTJS GRID and store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have EXT JS 4.2 Grid and store.

Now one page load grid get data from store and display on UI.

I have date drop down filter on page. on date selection of date filter one request should go to server fetch data from db and reload store with updated data, and grid should update with updated store value.

My issue is how can i unbind exiting store from grid load, set store params with date, then fetch new data in store and bind to grid. and show updated data on grid?

thanks in advance

this is code where grid is created , one button is created on click of which new params needs to pass to server

```
{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                style: 'margin-left: 152px;',
                width: 960,
                height: 'auto',
                cls: 'portlet full',
                items: Ext.getCmp('grid')

            }, {  //Create Button to fetch Grid Checked Data//
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            style: 'margin-left: 163px;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 59px;',
            items: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    name: 'Click me',
                    width:'40px',
                    handler: function() {
```

update =============================================

```
        Ext.create('store', {storeId: 'storetest2'}).load({
        params: {
            // To send Extra Params
            'lastname':'test2'
        },
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            // To Perform some call back operations
        }
    });
    scndStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('storetest2'),
    Ext.getCmp('grid').reconfigure(scndStore);
```

update =============================================

```
               })
         ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed with `this.getStore().load({ params: {test:'test1'}`,.. I was using filter and I was not clearing it before second load `.this.getStore().clearFilter(true);`

Answer (score 3):

> After getting data into the new store,you can use

```
grid.reconfigure(store, [columns])
```

> to change which store is bound to the grid..Please have a look [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure).

A simple working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/P3aww/14/)

> Update:Try this

```
var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
               model : 'store2Model',   //Don't miss to mention model 
               storeId: 'storetest2',
               proxy : {
                         type : 'ajax',
                         url  :'someUrl'
                         reader : {
                                    type : 'json',
                                    root : 'items' // depends 
                                   }
                        }
             });
 store2.load({
    params: {
        // To send Extra Params
        'lastname':'test2'
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        grid = Ext.getCmp('grid'); //First check whether you are getting this comp properly
        grid.reconfigure(store2);
    }
});
```

Comment: this code is not removing earlier data from grid and appending earlier data store again with grid..please help

Comment: @Poonam,please check the edit.I have added a simple working fiddle.

Comment: you have created 2 stores and reconfiguring second store to grid. I have also created 2 stores and `grid.reconfigure(scndStore);`. but it is not removing data of first store from grid and appending first store data to grid existing data

Comment: @PoonamBhatt : Move  Ext.getCmp('grid').reconfigure(records); in the callback:function(records){}

Comment: Hard luck...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null

Comment: It is fixed with         `this.getStore().load({
           params: {test:'test1'},`.. I was using filter and I was not clearing it before second load .`this.getStore().clearFilter(true);`

Comment: Was not aware of the filter.But thats grt!! :-).